# Define one-off Typescript interfaces

Tags: typescript

I've been using React for a while and I'm starting to incorporate Typescript into it. In my previous projects, I was used to creating large "container" objects like this:

```
const theme = {
  colors: {
    primary: '#00f',
    accent: '#f70',
  },
  sizes: {
    base: '16px',
  },
};
```

How could I define a type for such an object? It seems awkward that I have to define the interface by typing (pardon the pun) every single member of it, then repeat it all over to assign the values:

```
interface ThemeType { colors: ThemeColors, sizes: ThemeSizes }
interface ThemeColors { primary: string, accent: string }
interface ThemeSizes { base: string }

const theme : ThemeType = {
  // ...
};
```

Is there another way to do it? At least a more compact way?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something. Why do you have `const` behind the `interface` keyword? Is that valid Typescript syntax? And why is there an `=` after the name of the interface? Can you reproduce that code using the [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) just do you can remove the errors?

Comment: Do you *need* to type each of the composing parts? If not, you could just have a more monolithic interface - `interface ThemeType { colors: { primary: string, accent: string}, sizes: { base: string } }`

Comment: @AskYous Sorry, my mistake, I typed that code without thinking too much.

Comment: TS Also offers duck typing, You could cast it as the necessary interface while leaving the container as "any".

Comment: @VLAZ Your solution is at least less clumsy, thank you!

Comment: I suppose another question to ask is - do you need to reuse the interface? If not then...well, you can just directly assign the value - if you have `obj = { foo: "hello", bar: { baz: "world"}, quux: 42}` then `obj` will implicitly have the type `{ foo: string, bar: { baz: string }, quux: number}`. You wouldn't be able to refer to it, though but that might not be a problem if you only use it once - you'd still have type safety if you do `obj.foo = false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare the constant with no type annotation; its type will be inferred as:

```js
{
    colors: {
        primary: string;
        accent: string;
    };
    sizes: {
        base: string;
    };
}
```

If you need to use its type as an annotation elsewhere, you can write:

```js
type ThemeType = typeof theme
```

Then you can use `ThemeType` as an alias for the above type. If you want to refer to the types of the nested objects, they are `ThemeType['colors']` and `ThemeType['sizes']`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to define each sub-part of an interface if that is not used in your code:

```
interface ThemeType { colors: ThemeColors, sizes: ThemeSizes }
interface ThemeColors { primary: string, accent: string }
interface ThemeSizes { base: string }
```

These three interfaces could just be combined into one:

```
interface ThemeType { 
  colors: { 
    primary: string, 
    accent: string
  }, 
  sizes: { 
    base: string 
  } 
}
```

Which means that instead of having three interfaces each used once, you now only have a single one.

However, if you truly only ever use the interface once, then you don't necessarily need an interface - TypeScript will implicitly type your variable if you just assign to it:

```
const theme = {
  colors: {
    primary: '#00f',
    accent: '#f70',
  },
  sizes: {
    base: '16px',
  },
};
```

In this case `theme` implicitly has the type

```
{ 
  colors: { 
    primary: string, 
    accent: string
  }, 
  sizes: { 
    base: string 
  } 
}
```

just like before. However, you don't have to explicitly define it and you can't re-use it. Still, you do maintain type safety - doing `theme.colors.primary = 42` [will throw a compiler error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBFAWBTAtomBeGBvAUDGoANiAE4QBc2e+MADiQJbICGJAnpQOQDEADLwDNOAGmr5mwYIjBQu3AQHZeI6gF9R+CAwBeiClRowARswiIuARgBstAB4r86nKoDcOHAhSIAdEVIRveiZWNgwYABYAJhcgA)

Defining a type *can* be useful. An implicit type here will allow any strings to be used as values which is not strictly correct. For example:

```
const temp = theme.colors.primary;

theme.colors.accent = temp; //valid assignment and allowed by TS
theme.sizes.base = temp; //invalid assignment yet allowed by TS
```

You could alleviate that using what's called an "opaque type". This is quite simply a *type* that "hides" another type. The idea is that two identical opaque types are assignable to one another but two different opaque types aren't, even if the "hidden" type is the same for all. I'm going to use my favourite implementation of TypeScript opaque types from Drew Colthorp which is described in the article [Flavoring: Flexible Nominal Typing for TypeScript](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/01/15/typescript-flexible-nominal-typing/). Note: the implementation there calls it "Flavouring" which is (as far as I know) a term invented by Mr Colthorp and his team.

```
interface Flavoring<FlavorT> {
  _type?: FlavorT;
}
export type Flavor<T, FlavorT> = T & Flavoring<FlavorT>;
```

In short, this is all you need to define opaque types, the usage would be

```
type ColorHex = Flavour<string, "ColorHexValue">
type SizePx = Flavour<string, "SizePxValue">

let myColor: ColorHex = "#000";
let mySize: SizePx = "42px";

myColor = mySize; //compiler error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIBs4DcD2VQDmAPBtngCoB8yA3gFDLID6YAngA4QD8AXGprijkA3HQC+dNp35koRcgBoZgqsgC8ycsgBkyvIRICKlUZI4oAwjnR4AEhAAe6vXIDOYfCAJKARFZtQ9g4AanDoAK4QPpRm0gDKwABeEAAKThqkgkTunt7IPgnJaaERUTF06BBgyAC2rP54fA2Bjs4+AMQADN0+opXVdYUQfENpbQAsAEzsDr10dHXNzoNJEMLIAPQbCDg17MCVUMjQUHh0QA)

You have to pass the inner type (`string`) and an arbitrary but unique identifier for it (`"ColorHexValue"` and `"SizePxValue"`). The secret magic is in the second parameter - since the two don't match, the types are not equivalent. And since it's optional, you can *assign* values to it but you cannot assign a `ColorHex` value to a `SizePx` value and vice versa. This allows for very powerful usage of types for very minimal investment:

```
interface ThemeType { 
  colors: { 
    primary: ColorHex, 
    accent: ColorHex
  }, 
  sizes: { 
    base: SizePx 
  } 
}

const theme: ThemeType = {
  colors: {
    primary: '#00f',
    accent: '#f70',
  },
  sizes: {
    base: '16px',
  },
};

const temp = theme.colors.primary;

theme.colors.accent = temp; //valid assignment and allowed by TS
theme.sizes.base = temp; //invalid assignment blocked by TS
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=32&pc=60#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIBs4DcD2VQDmAPBtngCoB8yA3gFDLID6YAngA4QD8AXGprijkA3HQC+dNp35koRcgBoZgqsgC8ycsgBkyvIRICKlUZI4oAwjnR4AEhAAe6vXIDOYfCAJKARFZtQ9g4AanDoAK4QPpRm0gDKwABeEAAKThqkgkTunt7IPgnJaaERUTF0oJCwiCjkABYQALYQ5Oa0yAzICNZ4rnw0HYyM7PiNcFCsfP52jkqdjIhI4FM9gY6dYnOMrkkQfe3zyABGcK4QfIWpThsdEnTdIO7IYA3NfPVNLW0a9IzdAftfkMRsAxhM+AByADEAAYYTAIQpDosIMtkNCYAB2GGIjZI7a7QGHE5nSEARgAbOwHLjGJtxKYHk9II12M4Xp8AHT-XqckFg1imDnNbmrVyclHgdlNdjCZAAenlWDCwAAJshTjsCCBmlK4CB1WEbAB3CDqo6sTRxSSvCCcnbJcUklAaFmyhXy0DK9BqjWuLU61FgY42BAAazNx0t5DiQA)

It's worth pointing out that `ColorHex` won't actually validate that the string contains a valid hex representation. However, it still goes a long way to protecting you from accidentally assigning one string to another in the cases when that doesn't makes sense - assigning a colour to a size.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces only define the contract for a given object and don't allocate any memory, hence you can't provide initial values.

Not exactly analagous to your example, but you could get strong typing more concisely using classes rather than interfaces as follows:

```
    class ThemeColors { primary: string = '#00f'; accent: string = '#f70'};
    class ThemeSizes { base: string = '16px' };
    class ThemeType { colors: ThemeColors = new ThemeColors(); sizes: ThemeSizes = new ThemeSizes() } 
    const theme = new ThemeType()
```

As per comments below, alternatively you could also do something like this:

```
class ThemeType {
    colors = { primary: '#00f', accent: '#f70' };
    sizes = { base: '16px' };
}
const theme = new ThemeType();
```

Comment: Great! Can I define a monolithic class like this? `class ThemeType { colors: { primary:string = '#00f'; accent: string = '#f70'; }, sizes: { base: string = '16px' } }`

Comment: Yes, you'll just lose the strong typing of ThemeColors and ThemeSizes;  your type checking becomes just of a dictionary rather than your specific structure which may be completely fine for your use case anyway. It'll be a bit different to what you've given, but i'll update the answer shortly